# Adding comma and stop adding it after period

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, reactjs, forms

I am trying to format a currency field like this 1,222,333.00 but the regex I have allow me add comma after period like after .00 this. I don't want that. How can I stop it adding comma after period ? Any help pls. This is the regex I am using. `replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "$1,")` when I add number after period like this 1,222,333.123455556 or like this 2,333.444444 it should be just numbers without commas. when i add any number it add commas automatically and when i type period it still add commas automatically after period. the string i want is like this '1,222,333.9999'

Comment: Do you mean like this? `(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\S))` https://regex101.com/r/IDPFxX/1

Comment: Please show a string you wish to modify for your example.  Could it be  `"1222333.00"` or `"I want 1222333.00 now!"`?

Comment: Yes in your example when you add period it still adds comma after period. so it should stop adding comma after period like this. 1,222,333.1111111111 should be like this. when i add numbers after comma it should be just numbers after period no comma.

Comment: I see. When replying to comments that ask for clarification you should edit your question rather elaborating in a comment. Questions should be self-contained and not all readers read all comments. Also, please tell us if the string could be `"1222333"` (no cents).

Comment: I reply you and also edit my question. Thanks you.

Comment: when i add any number it add commas automatically and when i type period it still add commas automatically after period. the string i want is like this '1,222,333.9999'

Answer (score 3):

You can use number.toLocaleString('en-US')

```
console.log(number.toLocaleString('en-IN'));
// → 1,23,456.789
```

> Reference:
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString

Comment: Not only does this avoid the reinvention of the wheel, it reads better than a regex and simplifies testing.

Answer (score 0):

You can stop the regular expression from matching digits after the dot by adding a positive lookahead at the end. The new regular expression would be: `/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))(?=.*\.)/g`

Answer (score 0):

You could use this regular expression:

```
/(?<=\d)(?=(?:\d{3})+\.)/
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/3p3xLK/4/)

This regex can be made self-documenting by writing it in *free-spacing mode*:

```
/
(?<=\d)      # match is preceded by a digit (positive lookbehind)
(?=          # begin positive lookahead 
  (?:\d{3})  # match 3 digits in a non-capture group
  +          # execute non-capture group 1+ times
  \.         # match '.'
)            # end positive lookahead
/x           # free-spacing mode
```

Comment: this is good but how can i also be able to type comma? bc rn you only can type period.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Are you saying the string could look like this: `"12345,6789"`? If so, change `\.` to `[.,]`. I assume you noticed the SUBSTITUTION section at my Demo link.

Comment: sorry I should have been more clear. so when user type a number lets say one thousands ti will be like this 1,000 so user also can be able to add comma after typing number one and then three 0. Right now you can only type period and number in input. like this: user type any number 1 and then want to add comma 1, and then type other three number 345. also here is regex if you want to check `replace(/(\d)(?<=\d)(?=(?:\d{3})+(?=\.))/g, "$1,")`

Comment: Forget about the user typing anything. You simply need to tell us the possible patterns of the string you wish to modify and how each should be modified. Clearly, one possibility is `"ddddddd.dddd"`, where `"d"` represents a digit. You want that changed to `"d,ddd,ddd.dddd"`. What are the other possible patterns, if any? For example, is `"dd,dddd"` one? If so, are any substitutions be made to that string?  Is `"ddddddd"` a possible pattern?

Comment: If the string were `"1111111,1111"` would you want to replace it with 
`"1.111.111,1111"`, `"1 111 111,1111"`, `"1,111,111,1111"` or something else? (The last of these three possibilities seems to make no sense). Your question is a mess. The only reason I'm continuing to put time into answering is there are aspects I find interesting.

Answer (score 0):

`(num / 10000).replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ',').replace(/\.$/g, ',')`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your answer to provide more information as to how the code/pattern you've provided works, what you have changed, etc. Code-only answers might solve the problem of the original asker but they don't help future readers understand the solution.